# MAX and COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

- Column 1 - Date & Time Stamp
- Column 2 - Event (Data values)
- Column 3 - Criteria

My requirements are:

1. I want to find out the count of latest date (column 1) ignoring the time (have a repetition of dates & time)
2. Continuing the same formula, i want to use the COUNTIFS formula to get the count of the event based on the particular criteria.

Please help me, how to do the same in excel - let me know if any work around.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [mcve] and update your question!

Comment: the criteria for the event (not date) right ?